# Calculating factorials with numbers bigger than ints and longs in java?

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

Been searching here and google for a couple of days as well as asking my programming friends.
Unfortunately, i still don't understand how to change my code...

My program calculates the factorial of a given number. It then provides a number which represents how many digits the factorials answer includes. Then it sums the values of those digits together to give a total.

My program works for any number between 1! and 31!... If you put in anything over 31! (for example 50! or 100!) it doesn't work and just throws back minus numbers and no total.

I was hoping you guys could point me in the right direction or give me some advice.
I understand using BigIntegers maybe a solution however i don't understand them personally, hence coming here.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
    package java20;

    /**
    * Program to calculate the factorial of a given number.
    * Once implemented, it will calculate how many digits the answer includes.
    * It will then sum these digits together to provide a total.
     * @author shardy
     * date: 30/09/2012
     */

    //import java.math.BigInteger;
    public class Java20 {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Using given number stored in factorialNo, calculates factorial
    //currently only works for numbers between 1! and 31! :(
        int fact= 1;
        int factorialNo = 10;

        for (int i = 1; i <= factorialNo; i++)
            {
               fact=fact*i;
            }

        System.out.println("The factorial of " + factorialNo + 
                " (or " + factorialNo + "!) is: " + fact);

        //Using answer stored in fact, calculates how many digits the answer has
        final int answerNo = fact;
        final int digits = 1 + (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(answerNo));

        System.out.println("The number of digits in the factorials "
                + "answer is: " + digits);        

        //Using remainders, calculates each digits value and sums them together
        int number = fact;
        int reminder;
        int sum = 0;

        while(number>=1)
            {
             reminder=number%10; 
             sum=sum+reminder;
             number=number/10;
            }

        System.out.println("The total sum of all the " + digits 
                + " idividual digits from the answer of the factorial of " 
                + factorialNo + " is: " + sum);

      }
    }
```

Comment: This could be a helpful link http://haiteq.com/2011/08/03/for-coders-only-how-to-use-biginteger-in-java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BigInteger in java, it has as much numbers as you want

```
    BigInteger fact= BigInteger.ONE;
    int factorialNo = 10;

    for (int i = 2; i <= factorialNo; i++){
      fact = fact.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i)));
    }

    System.out.println("The factorial of " + factorialNo +
                                " (or " + factorialNo + "!) is: " + fact);
   final int digits = fact.toString().length();

   BigInteger number = new BigInteger(fact.toString());
   BigInteger reminder;
   BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
   BigInteger ten = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(10));

   while(number.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)>=0)
     {
     reminder=number.mod(ten);
     sum=sum.add(reminder);
     number=number.divide(ten);
     }

     System.out.println("The total sum of all the " + digits
                     + " idividual digits from the answer of the factorial of "
                     + factorialNo + " is: " + sum
```

**EDIT**: the code is improved to be compatible with author's code

Comment: Thanks so much, this is great and works very well.
Unfortunately, its then not compatible with the math.log10 or the while loop :(

Comment: Please don't forget to mark it as an answer, so the others may see when having the same problem.

Comment: Of course :) I just want to fix the math.log10 problem too first...
It almost seems completely incompatible..

Comment: Just to confirm, the "final int digits = fact.toString().length();" tells you how many digits are in the factorials answer? Seems a lot simpler than the Math.Log10 way?

Comment: It simply tells you how many characters the string has = number of digits. This is the way I always use in Java.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again. You've really helped and its much appreciated :) Definitely got to remember that one.

Answer (score 1):

> If you put in anything over 31! (for example 50! or 100!) it doesn't
>   work and just throws back minus numbers and no total.

This is because primitive integer types are subject to [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) when you exceed their maximum possible value.  Which computing factorials has a tendency to do.

> I was hoping you guys could point me in the right direction or give me
>   some advice. I understand using BigIntegers maybe a solution however i
>   don't understand them personally, hence coming here.

You are correct that using `BigInteger` is one possible solution.  You can, for instance, do something like:

```
public BigInteger factorial(int num) {
    if (num < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not today!");
    }

    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

    for (int next = 2; next <= num; next++) {
        result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(Integer.toString(next, 10)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your message "Not today" is not informative, so better to use something like "Factorial is not defined for negative numbers [" + num + "]"

Comment: @Tim - Agreed.  The point of the example code is to indicate that negative/invalid values should be handled *somehow*, not to recommend a specific approach for doing so.  One could argue, perhaps, that returning `null` is an equally valid way to deal with the issue, or that some other exception-type should be used.  The important point is to have some check for invalid numbers.  What happens inside of that check is somewhat up to personal preference and/or project/organization coding guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calculating things like (m!/n!), you are better off using logarithms of factorials.

You should also consider these two improvements:

1. Memoize, don't recalculate.  Store those hard-earned values once you calculate them.
2. You should be using the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) to calculate factorials.  The way you're doing it with a loop is the naive thing that is presented to students.  There's a nice implementation of `ln(gamma(x))` in [Numerical Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521880688).

You can always use BigDecimal if you must, but it's a last resort.  You should still consider these points.

There's a gamma function implementation available from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/math/special/Gamma.html).  The source code might not be as familiar as the naive approach, but if you see how it's done it'll be obvious that it's more efficient even for moderate arguments.

Comment: Counting the factorial with loops is the simplest possible way. Another way is to use recursion, but is it limited due to stack size.

Comment: Both are simple, but inefficient and naive.  Gamma function is the serious way to go.

Comment: Could you please indicate the complexity of the method?

Comment: It's a function call.  No looping, no recursion, no stack frames.  I didn't count operations, but it's the same for 2! as it is for 100000!.  It's far, far less than either looping or recursion, and the advantage only increases for large input values.

Comment: If I wrap the loop into a function it will still be O(N), but "It's a function call".

Comment: Sorry Tim, you don't know what you're talking about.  Go find a gamma function implementation and see how many operations are required to evaluate 100!